# How to address selection bias in a diff-in-diff study?

Tags: econometrics, causality, difference-in-difference, selection-bias

We know that selection bias occurs when the treatment and control groups are not comparable, leading to differences in the outcome that are not solely due to the treatment.

First edit: By selection bias, I mean treatment mechanism is nonrandom. This would also lead to differences in the outcome that are not solely due to the treatment.

Second edit: I think I didn't make my question precise. I am interested in effects of a policy on an outcome. The treatment group in my case is nonrandom (hence selection bias) in the sense that it is decided before the actual treatment based on their observed covariates like income. The intervention didn't create a treatment group; the group was formed based on its characteristics. How does one address this nonrandom-assignment-led selection bias? Is DiD useful? What are alternatives if not?

How does one address the problem due to selection bias in a DiD setting? Or is DiD not suitable for any study that faces selection bias problem? How to make DiD results credible when faced with selection bias? What other econometric methods can give credible causal estimates of the intervention in the above case?

Comment: Treatment control groups being “not comparable” is not necessarily selection bias. Selection bias is a very specific type of bias due to some observations being omitted due to characteristics in the *outcome* variable. In any case, under parallel trends, DiD identifies the treatment-on-treated parameter.

Comment: Yes. Please see my edit: I have clarified what I mean by SB.

Comment: @YashaswiMohanty, yes under PT, DiD gives ATT, but the question is how to make ATT credible (in causal sense) when there is a problem of selection bias (nonrandom treatment mechanism).

Comment: Random assignment of the treatment implies that potential outcomes are independent of treatment assignment, in which case you identify the ATE not just the ToT. I think the question you really want to ask is how some confounders can actually violate the parallel trend assumption, the answer to which of course depends on the specific question you are trying to answer.

Comment: Not sure how what you are saying relates to my question. I have a setting in the observational data where treatment assignment is nonrandom. My question is how to make the treatment effects causally more credible.

Comment: My point is that the random assignment of treatment is strictly unnecessary to the DiD setting where one is trying to identify the treatment on the treated parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144894/discussion-between-yashaswi-mohanty-and-funcard).